# String pattern matching in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-matching

Please help me out in writing a generic  SQL query for the below scenarios.
Based on the data in the table2 the output is decided.For Eg1, if AB* is present in table2,the output would be AB01,AB02. 
Eg2 - AB02 is present in Table2, only AB02 is in output
Eg3 - * is present in Table2, all the data in Table1 is in output

Scenario 1

```
Table1  
AB01  
AB02  
BE01  
GH01  

Table2  
AB*

Output  
AB01  
AB02
```

---

```
Scenario 2

Table1  
AB01  
AB02  
BE01  
GH01  

Table2  
AB02

Output   
AB02
```

---

Scenario 3

```
Table1

AB01  
AB02  
BE01  
GH01  

Table2  
*

Output  
AB01  
AB02  
BE01  
GH01
```

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. It seems like you are trying to store the rules in the database for how to join to two tables together. This screams of poor design and requires you to use dynamic sql. Perhaps if you share some clear details it will be more obvious what you want. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: mysql  mysql @B001

Answer (score 0):

Use `rlike` on a cross join between the tables:

```
select * 
  from table1 t1, table2 t2
  where t1.col1 rlike t2.col2;
```

You may need to tweak your expressions in table2 to become standard regex patterns, but that should be easy. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
select a.* from table1 a join table2 b on a.field like '%'+replace(b.field,'*','')+'%'
```

Comment: Worked for me for all three scenarios